# What's the exact number of types in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Besides the data primitives and structures you could found in other languages, what's the full list of types in Erlang?

For example, what's the type of the socket handle? and what about ets handle?

Moreover, which types are impossible to be serialized and exchanged between nodes? I think the socket handle must be one of them, right?

Even among processes within the same node, the socket handle is shared, right? That's the exception of share-nothing principle?

What's the behavior of GC against such shared stuff? And what's the socket implementation in Erlang? I think it's not a port, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The socket is in port type, which is implemented in built-in driver.

Within the same node, the socket could be shared by multiple processes; all processes could calls upon the socket, and when the owner process exits, the socket would be closed.

And I try to send the socket to the remote process (within a different node), when the remote process try to access the socket, e.g. send(), it would raise an error with Reason "closed".

Answer (score 9):

There are very few types in erlang, and you can refer to the functions is_???(Term) of the erlang module to get the list of built in elementary types:

- atom
- bitstring
- float
- function
- integer
- list
- map
- pid
- port
- reference
- tuple

there is a second list which is derived from elementary types:

- binary : a bitstring which size is a multiple of byte size
- boolean : the atoms true and  false
- number : an integer or a float
- record : a tuple which first term is an atom representing the record name (the compiler uses a record definition to access to the different elements of the tuple by symbol rather than index)

Then you can consider that you can create an infinite number of types based on any combination of those elementary types. In some program you will see some declaration such as:

```
-type orddict() :: [{Key :: term(), Value :: term()}].
```

or

```
-spec is_key(Key, Orddict) -> boolean() when
      Key :: term(),
      Orddict :: orddict().
```

Those information are not used directly by the Erlang compiler, they are used by external tools such as Dializer and are not mandatory to get a valid code. The main feature in Erlang is not type declaration, but pattern matching. Thus, if you call a function and expect a return value of the form `{ok,Value}` or `{error,Reason}`  you will write something like:

```
Result = case f(Par) of
    {ok,Value} -> resultWhenOk(Value);
    {error,Reason} -> resultWhenError(Reason)
end;
```

or if you don't care about error management:

```
% get the Name and Age of the employee whose id is Id in a list of people List
% using a function that return a tuple of the form
% {PeopleType, Id, Name,Surname,Age,Sex}
{ok,{employee,Id,Name,_,Age,_}} = find_people(Id,List);
```